# Finding component tree in Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: java, android, tree, components

I have searched in the internet but all I get is answers on older version of android studio on how the components treeioioon was and has been taken from the palette. I couldnt find any explanation on where to get that tree in version 2.3.3. Where is it located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are in design mode that is below on the left.

[image: Component tree]

Comment: Worked. Thanks and that downvote was accidental, gracias.

Comment: No problem, I am very glad that it helped you. Mark my answer as the correct answer so others can know your problem is solved. Happy Coding :) @shaminarry

Answer (score 1):

You must be in "Design" mode of your XML file to see the Component Tree. When you are in "Text" mode, the Component Tree is automatically hidden. In the lower-left corner of the code panel, there are two tabs: Design and Text. Click the "Design" tab to reveal the Component Tree.